# Hibernate : aggregate two entities in one class to retrieve data with one HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have one class like this :

```
public class BookAuthor {

  private Book book;
  private Author author;
}
```

Book and Author are defined as entities.

When I try to retrieve the data, this way :

```
final String selectCols = "NEW BookAuthor(b,a)";
final org.hibernate.Query q = createQuery(selectCols, params, filters);
result = q.list();
return result;
```

When Hibernate executes "q.list()", it performs one query to retrieve the book's and author's IDs, and then iterates the results to get the information about authors and books. That is, in my log, there would be something like this :

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from authors a , books b
```

And then for each row :

```
select a.ID, a.name
where a.ID = ?

select b.ID, b.title
where b.ID = ?
```

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to get the results with one query to improve performance like this ? :

```
select a.ID, a.name, b.ID, b.title
from authors a , books b
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

Entities are defined referring to their tables and column names like:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "AUTHOR";
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
protected Long id;
```

I think there is no DB constraint between author and book (this was only an example of the actual entities, but let's say that there could be some anonymous books with no author). 
Thanks JB Nizet, I will retrieve the query and post it here in a while.

Comment: How are the entities defined? What is the query that you're executing? Why don't you simply select all the books, or all the authors, and use the association between them to get the author (or the books)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not look at hibernate queries as SQL Queries. I guess what you are after is hibernates lazy-loading:

If you fetch BookAuthor and the properties Book and Author are lazy loaded then it will be slow (because hibernate has to make 3 Querys in total for one Entity)

So depending on your situation, you can disable lazy loading for your BookAuthor in your mapping - hibernate will then fetch all data in one select query.

Comment: I favoured this response, but I finally couldn't make it work with that approach of a class containing two entities. I always got many SQL queries executed. I just changed the select statement into something like this : 
     select NEW map(a.ID, a.name, b.ID, b.title) 
and then map the results into the class attributes. Not an elegant solution, but at least it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The usual case for this is when you want to create a list of items. In this case you know what fields are of interest to you. So you specify those in your projection (in SQL the SELECT clause).

How you are suggesting doing it is fine. Once you have the relations mapped Hibernate will do it in one join because you are specifying a Projection list.

The difference is that you will now get back a list of Object[] instances. Hibernate will leave the unmarshalling into entities to you.